# How to resolve "multiple definition of 'main()'" C compiling error?

Tags: c

I recently started learning C and must create program that scanf two integer values from standard input separated by a space then printf the sum of these two integers. Must be able to accept negative values. I'm using repl.it to write code 1st then pasting in .c to compile.

Attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {    

    int number1, number2, sum;

    printf("Enter two integers: ");

    scanf("%d", &number1);

    scanf("%d", &number2);

    // calculating sum

    sum = number1 + number2;      

    printf("%d + %d = %d", number1, number2, sum);

    return 0;
}
```

**[OP originally said "Except this prints" -- but this is not program output -- this is error output during the compilation process before the program ever ran]**

Except when I try to compile the IDE outputs the errors

```
/tmp/t2-8eec00.o: In function `main':
t2.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
/tmp/t1-f81f83.o:t1.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/t3-72a7ab.o: In function `main':
t3.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
/tmp/t1-f81f83.o:t1.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/main-2c962b.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
/tmp/t1-f81f83.o:t1.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
exit status 1
```

The output is wrong so what mistake did I make? What's the correct method to get expected values?

(eg 1+2=3)

platform using it on:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJElj.jpg

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: How are you compiling this? Did you paste it in twice by accident?

Comment: This is a link time error. Show the command line you are using for compiling. If you are using a IDE, you probably have two files in your project, with main() defined in each.

Comment: @Tarik added edit of how code is being compiled

Comment: Looks like you're trying to compile multiple files that each have a `main` function.

Comment: I think you have t2.c, t3.c and main.c file in the same folder or workspace. your code is working. tested using [onlinegdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com). Please try to indent your code for readability.

Answer (score 5):

This is a project management issue. The IDE shows that you have 4 files, all of which conflict with each other. You have `t1.c`, `t2.c`, `t3.c`, and `main.c`. They all try to define `main()`, so in fact you have a 4-way conflict.

Functions in C exist in a *global* namespace across the whole project.

Remove all files from the project that don't have the version of main() you actually want, and re-compile. -- OR rename the functions in the other files to mutually distinct names different than `main()`. You may get a warning that these functions are never used, but the project will compile.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that you have defined the main function multiple times, try to compile it in a new file. The code is correct, so try to compile the code by creating new file.